# Target page does not render after using back-button

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, back-button

Dear community and readers:

programming a small website I have encountered for first time a strange behavior. What I basically do is that I hide the body until page load and then fade it in. Via onClick on a link in the navigation I use redirectPage and the procedure repeats with the target link page. So this works all wonderful but when visiting the site in the browser and using the back button it seems that the pages visited before are not rendering. Latest Google Chrome versions are doing it, Firefox, Safari fail. Strangely own Safari, clicking the back button three times forces the homepage to load again. This happens most of the times but not all time.

Has anyone an idea how I could achieve in my function to force a render anytime the back button is pressed. Might be a silly question but I really never came across this issue. I tried some snippets I found and worked around them my own way. They did not work and I would rather understand the problem than choose pure cosmetics.

Thank you for your input!

```
    // Document on load.
$(function(){

    gotToNextSection();
    loaderPage();
    ScrollNext();
    moreProjectSlider();

    // Animate
    contentWayPoint();


})();


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    $("body").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });


    $("a.transition").click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      

    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }

});
```

Comment: I fixed your IIFE, you were not matching opening and closing brackets. Can you retry your code or provide a jsFiddle link?

Comment: Thanks Mann from Reno, did you correct the code in my own post?

Comment: I did, try the edited code and see if it fixes anything. Also a jsFiddle would be helpful in trying to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't know how to isolate the code from the use case but I have the problem online on www.schmackes.cl. It is no more than a simple boot strap set up, but using safari or firefox showcases the exact same problem. Thanks for the brackets, I just notices.